# Why do my hover annotations have NaN instead of my values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot-annotations

```
import yfinance as yf
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Dates to get stock data
start_date = "2020-01-01"
end_date = "2023-06-15"

# Fetch Tesla stock data
tesla_data = yf.download("TSLA", start=start_date, end=end_date)
tesla_weekly_data = tesla_data.resample("W").agg({"Open": "first", "High": "max", "Low": "min", "Close": "last", "Volume": "sum"}).dropna()

# Get the latest closing price
latest_price = tesla_weekly_data['Close'][-1]

# Create additional plot
close_price = tesla_weekly_data['Close']
apd = mpf.make_addplot(close_price, color='cyan', width=2)

# Plot the candlestick chart
fig, axes = mpf.plot(tesla_weekly_data,
                     type='candle',
                     addplot=apd,
                     style='yahoo',
                     title='Tesla Stock Prices',
                     ylabel='Price',
                     xlabel='Date',
                     volume=True,
                     ylabel_lower='Volume',
                     volume_panel=1,
                     figsize=(16, 8),
                     returnfig=True
                     )

# Move the y-axis labels to the left side
axes[0].yaxis.tick_left()
axes[1].yaxis.tick_left()

# Adjust the position of the y-axis label for price
axes[0].yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.08, 0.5)

# Adjust the position of the y-axis label for volume
axes[1].yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.08, 0.5)

# Set y-axis label for price and volume
axes[0].set_ylabel('Price', rotation=0, labelpad=20)
axes[1].set_ylabel('Volume', rotation=0, labelpad=20)

# Make the legend box
handles = axes[0].get_legend_handles_labels()[0]
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red')
green_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='green')
cyan_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='cyan')
handles = handles[:2] + [red_patch, green_patch, cyan_patch]
labels = ["Price Up", "Price Down", "Closing Price"]
axes[0].legend(handles=handles, labels=labels)

# Add a box to display the current price
latest_price_text = f"Current Price: ${latest_price:.2f}"
box_props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='white', edgecolor='black', alpha=0.8)
axes[0].text(0.02, 0.95, latest_price_text, transform=axes[0].transAxes, fontsize=12, verticalalignment='top', bbox=box_props)

# Define hover label format
hover_label_format = [
    ("Open: ", lambda x: f"${x:.2f}"),
    ("High: ", lambda x: f"${x:.2f}"),
    ("Low: ", lambda x: f"${x:.2f}"),
    ("Close: ", lambda x: f"${x:.2f}"),
    ("Volume: ", lambda x: f"{int(x):,}"),
]

# Function to create hover annotations
def hover_annotations(data):
    annot = pd.DataFrame(index=data.index, columns=data.columns)
    annot_visible = False

    texts = []

    def onmove(event):
        nonlocal annot_visible

        if event.inaxes == axes[0]:
            index = int(event.xdata)
            if index >= len(data.index):
                return

            values = data.iloc[index]
            for label, formatter in hover_label_format:
                value = values[label.rstrip(': ')]
                if np.isnan(value):
                    annot.iloc[index][label.rstrip(': ')] = ""
                else:
                    annot.iloc[index][label.rstrip(': ')] = f"{label}{formatter(value)}"

            annot_visible = True
        else:
            annot_visible = False

        for t, text, (x, y) in zip(texts, annot.values, zip([event.xdata] or [], [event.ydata] or [])):
            if isinstance(x, (list, np.ndarray)):
                x = x[0] if len(x) > 0 and not np.isnan(x[0]) else None
            if isinstance(y, (list, np.ndarray)):
                y = y[0] if len(y) > 0 and not np.isnan(y[0]) else None

            if x is not None and y is not None:
                t.set_position((x, y))
                t.set_text('\n'.join(map(str, text)))
                t.set_visible(annot_visible)

        fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    for _ in data.index:
        t = axes[0].text(0, 0, '', visible=False, ha='left', va='top')
        texts.append(t)

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', onmove)

    return annot


# Attach hover annotations to the plot
annotations = hover_annotations(tesla_weekly_data)

# Display the chart
plt.show()
```

If you run the code, instead of showing open high, low, close, and volume, its showing an error.

[image]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The code is working fine and reproducible.  You appear to be isolating `values = data.iloc[index]` OK, and the resulting `values` is of type Pandas.Series which is fine.  I am trying to understand what you are doing after that, especially with the `annot` dataframe.  The code seems way overly complicated at that point since what you want to display is simply inside the Series `values` and only needs to be formatted.  I will play with it some more and see what I can figure.  Seems that `annot` and the zipping and other stuff is way more complex than need be.  Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: `annot.values` is almost entirely `nan`.   Is that intended to be some kind of cache?   If not, then for sure the code is way overcomplicated.  If so, if it is intended to be a cache, why not prefil the entire thing?  I would try to rework that part of the code and get rid of `texts` and `annot`.  Simply format the Series `values` and display.

Comment: If @Daniel Goldfarb's answer works, you should accept their answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified your code a little bit.  The following works for me:

```py
import yfinance as yf
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Dates to get stock data
start_date = "2020-01-01"
end_date = "2023-06-15"

# Fetch Tesla stock data
tesla_data = yf.download("TSLA", start=start_date, end=end_date)
tesla_weekly_data = tesla_data.resample("W").agg(
        {"Open": "first", "High": "max", "Low": "min", "Close": "last", "Volume": "sum"}
    ).dropna()

# Get the latest closing price
latest_price = tesla_weekly_data['Close'][-1]

# Create additional plot
close_price = tesla_weekly_data['Close']
apd = mpf.make_addplot(close_price, color='cyan', width=2)

# Plot the candlestick chart
fig, axes = mpf.plot(tesla_weekly_data,
                     type='candle',
                     addplot=apd,
                     style='yahoo',
                     title='Tesla Stock Prices',
                     ylabel='Price',
                     xlabel='Date',
                     volume=True,
                     ylabel_lower='Volume',
                     volume_panel=1,
                     figsize=(16, 8),
                     returnfig=True
                     )

# Move the y-axis labels to the left side
axes[0].yaxis.tick_left()
axes[1].yaxis.tick_left()

# Adjust the position of the y-axis label for price
axes[0].yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.08, 0.5)

# Adjust the position of the y-axis label for volume
axes[1].yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.08, 0.5)

# Set y-axis label for price and volume
axes[0].set_ylabel('Price', rotation=0, labelpad=20)
axes[1].set_ylabel('Volume', rotation=0, labelpad=20)

# Make the legend box
handles = axes[0].get_legend_handles_labels()[0]
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red')
green_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='green')
cyan_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='cyan')
handles = handles[:2] + [red_patch, green_patch, cyan_patch]
labels = ["Price Up", "Price Down", "Closing Price"]
axes[0].legend(handles=handles, labels=labels)

# Add a box to display the current price
latest_price_text = f"Current Price: ${latest_price:.2f}"
box_props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='white', edgecolor='black', alpha=0.8)
axes[0].text(0.02, 0.95, latest_price_text, transform=axes[0].transAxes,
             fontsize=12, verticalalignment='top', bbox=box_props)

# Function to create hover annotations
def hover_annotations(data):

    annot_visible = False
    annot = axes[0].text(0, 0, '', visible=False, ha='left', va='top')

    def onmove(event):
        nonlocal annot_visible
        nonlocal annot

        if event.inaxes == axes[0]:
            index = int(event.xdata)
            if index >= len(data.index):
                index = -1
            elif index < 0:
                index = 0
            values = data.iloc[index]
            mytext = (f"{values.name.date().strftime('%m/%d/%Y'):}\n"+
                      f"O: {values['Open']:.2f}\n"+
                      f"H: {values['High']:.2f}\n"+
                      f"L: {values['Low']:.2f}\n"+
                      f"C: {values['Close']:.2f}\n"+
                      f"V: {values['Volume']:.0f}"
                     )

            annot_visible = True
        else:
            mytext = ''
            annot_visible = False

        annot.set_position((event.xdata,event.ydata))
        annot.set_text(mytext)
        annot.set_visible(annot_visible)
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', onmove)

    return annot


# Attach hover annotations to the plot
annotations = hover_annotations(tesla_weekly_data)

# Display the chart
plt.show()
```

I don't know what the problem was, but I completely got rid of the array of `texts` and the DataFrame `annot` (but I reused the name `annot` for a single annotation, what you were previously calling `t`).  I also got rid of all the looping through these things, and the complicated formatting lambdas which seemed to me very unneccessary.  At any rate, the above works for me.